# Get all visible nodes of mat-tree

Tags: angular, tree

Is there a straightforward way using Angular's `Mat-Tree` to get an array of all visible nodes?

`exampleTree.treeControl.nodes` returns an array of all nodes, and `exampleTree.treeControl.isExpanded(node)` can be used to see if a given node is expanded, so you could traverse the tree and algorithmically check - if a node isn't expanded then its children aren't visible.

However, it seems like there should be an easier way to do this, maybe by using whatever data structure Angular uses to actually render the tree elements in the DOM?

I'm working with a simple flat tree, so the following example from Angular should apply here: https://stackblitz.com/angular/qmyvoopvrlg?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 3):

The `_expandedData` property on `MatTreeFlatDataSource` is the data returned when connecting to the datasource, and contains the current visible nodes based on the expansion status.

See https://github.com/angular/components/blob/d5d7db4c834e45a75ba5382cfd06d28661b07a30/src/material/tree/data-source/flat-data-source.ts#L132

While you could as of the current version access the `_expandedData` property directly, it's not part of the official API documentation, so the most proper way would be to connect to the data source using the `connect` method and use the value from the returned Observable.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of old, but wanted to show  how I was able to access the _expandedData list for a project I've been working on:

1. add a CollectionViewer interface and an array to hold the current _expandedData:

```
 import { CollectionViewer, ListRange } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
 ...
 dataSourceViewer: CollectionViewer = {
  viewChange: new Observable<ListRange>()
 };
 expandedNodeList:any = [];
```

2. In my ngOnInit() method, subscribe to the datasource.connect() Observable, passing the "dataSourceViewer" CollectionViewer:

```
  this.dataSource.connect(this.dataSourceViewer).subscribe(data => {
    this.expandedNodeList = data;
  })
```

3. Any time a nested folder is opened or closed, the list of expanded nodes will be updated.

There are probably better ways to do this (I'm still very much an Angular newb) but this worked well for my purposes.

Comment: it is the direct answer, you saved my day